# Delphi 2006 proper use of END

Tags: delphi, if-statement, case, delphi-2006

Look at this code:

```
if Poruka(BM_UWARN, GetMsg('Da li zaista želite da odbijete nalog?')) = mrOk then
  begin
    tmps := TRN.ss;
    TrnPom.ss := TRN.ss;
    RadnikOdbio.l := AdresniSlog.Rabotnik;
    if Zakljucaj(1011, tmps, 3) then
      begin
        FRazlogOdbNal.ShowModal;
        case FRazlogOdbNal.ModalResult of
          mrOk:              
            BeBankComment.ss := FRazlogOdbNal.beRazlogOdbijanja.ss;              
          else
            Otkljucaj(1011, tmps, 3);
            exit;
        end;
      end;
   end;
```

It is not important what this code does, what I need help with is did I use enough `ENDs` in this part of code. So the first `END` is of `CASE` statement. Second `END` closes `BEGIN` of `if Zakljucaj(1011,tmps,3)` and the last `END` is closing `BEGIN` of starting `IF`. Is this the right way to close them, does compiler now which end refers to which part of the code? And also, does compiler knows that the `else` part refers to `case` statement?
If not, is there a way to explicitly do this?

Comment: The compiler would not complain if you put an extra `begin` after the `case .. else` statement.

Comment: Yes, I see it now, thanks.

Comment: The correct comment above should have been an extra compound `begin/end` statement after the `else`. Sorry if I was not clear on that point.

Comment: @LURD I understood you, but thanks for explanation, it might help somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is syntactically correct. The indentation is however a little off, you should not indent the `begin` of a block. The default behavior of the Rad Studio auto formatter is to align them like this:

```
if Poruka(BM_UWARN, GetMsg('Da li zaista želite da odbijete nalog?')) = mrOk then
begin
  tmps := TRN.ss;
  TrnPom.ss := TRN.ss;
  RadnikOdbio.l := AdresniSlog.Rabotnik;
  if Zakljucaj(1011, tmps, 3) then
  begin
    FRazlogOdbNal.ShowModal;
    case FRazlogOdbNal.ModalResult of
      mrOk:
        BeBankComment.ss := FRazlogOdbNal.beRazlogOdbijanja.ss;
    else
      Otkljucaj(1011, tmps, 3);
      exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The rest of what you state in your question is correct.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I was confused if the compiler is going think that the `else` part is from `if` and not `case` statement. Thanks again.

Comment: No, that is not the case, the first `else` after the `case` will be part of it, if you omit the `else` here, the compiler will encounter an `end` instead and know that the `case` is over at that point.

Comment: "_you should not indent the begin of a block_" - That's just like, your opinion, man.

Comment: "*The Rad Studio auto formatter aligns them like this*" - formatting is customizable and subject to user preference.

Comment: And in addition to what Remy said, the built in formatter still has a few bugs and quirks, even in the nth iteration.